# Supercomputers and undergraduates?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, computer-science

Is it common for an undergraduate to run its thesis (evolutionary genomics) in a supercomputer? In my country, few supercomputers exist, but I'm not sure how it is for bachelors in the US or Europe. I am writing my application to graduate school abroad and I want to know if it is a remarkable point I can use as hook to begin my statement.

Comment: Could you give some idea to those of us not knowledgeable of the topic how your topic requires the use of supercomputers. I feel that you have a wrong idea about how supercomputers are used and how working with one is different from working with a regular computer.

Answer (score 2):

If by "supercomputer" you mean a "computer cluster," there are lots of people with such experience in the US and Europe, and many universities even have their own. (My university, for instance, operates its own 25,000-core cluster.) If you mean "supercomputer" a machine like one on the [Top 500](http://www.top500.org), that may be worth mentioning. However, indicating that you have experience running calculations in high-performance computing environments is certainly worthwhile to mention if it's relevant for your graduate program.

Comment: Agreed. I think he meant a cluster - which is fairly common for undergraduate researchers to use. But if he worked with Watson, then that's another story..